# Printing bits in a buffer with C?

Tags: c, io, fwrite

What is the best way in C to write and read to/from a file a specific amount of bits at a time say the first 16 bits or 12 of the lower half of an integer. I can't seem to find any threads or documentation on it other than to use fwrite. I may not be sure but I do not think I can write a specific amount of bits and would need a buffer but can anyone direct me in the correct way to perform this?

Comment: No, you cannot write an arbitrary number of bits. A full byte is the smallest amount of data you can write.

Comment: Store the bits in a byte one at the time, by using bitwise operations and shifts. The byte would act as a buffer. Once the number of bits "pushed" in the byte reaches 8[\*], you can output the byte to the file and start over again. You'll obviously have to flush the final byte, if the last bits are less than 8[\*]
[*] or whatever the limit is on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

With the available APIs, the smallest amount of info you can write in a file at a time is 1 byte. To achieve what you want, you have to read the byte from the file, modify it using bitwise operators and write it back to the file. In case you are writing data as a stream, you would have to call fwrite once each byte is complete or if you are done. You would then have to pad the last byte with zeros or ones whichever is more appropriate in view of the fact that the file system will keep track of the file size in bytes. To do otherwise would require a file system that provides bit level operations and the corresponding support at the operating system level.

In fact, the smallest physical amount of data that can be written to a disk is a sector of 512 bytes and more recently 4096 bytes. At the file system level, several sectors are bundled together into a block. The operating system "hides" this fact and allows us to deal with individual bytes.

What seems to make this question **sound** stupid is the fact that we are so used to the current file abstraction that it has become like second nature.  However, behind the scenes a lot is going on to support this illusion.